# Using WatiN to crawl to next page on google

Tags: c#, watin

How can I navigate to the next page using [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net) ?

I need to automate clicking on the page numbers on the bottom from 1, 2, until the end...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines should get you started:

```
var ie = new IE();
ie.Link(Find.ByText("1")).Click();
```

While it's really basic, it should do the job. You could throw that in a simple loop and be done with it.

Good luck!